# Fixed window size app development for Mac OS X

Tags: apple, appstore, osx

I am developing a rather eye-candy application which is to be released on Mac App Store.

Due to its graphics intensive use, it would save a great deal of time on UI end if the app could be released with a fixed size main frame-dialog.

I did try doing a search regarding App Store policies on the matter but could not find anything.

Is the distribution of fixed-size frame [productivity] apps are allowed within the App Store if they conform with other design guidelines?

Comment: Would help to know the nature of what your app will do. For example, does it show data in a table view, or does it display images and allow you to apply filters or something? Also, what frameworks/IDE are you using to build it (Xcode + Interface Builder and Cocoa, or MonoMac, etc.?)

Comment: Hello. I am developing using the Qt framework. The app is like an "organiser". Has a left pane to go to sections and then two more panes which display various content and accept inputs etc. One of these areas might have table view or list view but most of the view items are also custom designed. What do you think? Thank you.

Comment: Do you take into account display sizes you are gonna show your app on, starting from smallest notebooks and ending with biggest displays Mac have (with retina?).

Comment: Note the existence of apps in the Mac App Store that have fixed-size windows.

Comment: Is your app intended to be used a lot?  Having a fixed window size may be very annoying to your users.  Beware of emphasizing style over usability.  Also beware of emphasizing ease of coding over ease of use.

Comment: Address Book is a fixed-size window, but be aware that it is likely to change in 10.9 due to it's skeuomorphic design.

Comment: @JBRWilkinson I can resize the Address Book window just fine in 10.7.5.

Comment: Oh okay. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

An app will not be rejected only because it has a fixed window size.

Although such a design choice could result in an inferior useabity. And that could be a reason for refusal.